# proper DNS setup for Dedicated server

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have some problems with .hr domains (croatian domain) and I think I've messed up DNS records.

For example:   jelisavacwlan.hr work ok, but centartepiha.hr  sometimes get unaccessible (even ping doesn't work).

Even now (at time of writing) centartepiha.hr is not accessible and looking on access log on server there is no request coming in port 80.

The bind9 service is working just fine and answering every request.

Server has domain (gamuru.com) and has defined a host as ns1.gamuru.com.
NS2 is on ns0.xname.org.

gamuru.com:

```
A         @  =>  144.76.173.238
CNAME     *  =>  @
CNAME     ftp  =>  @
CNAME     www  =>  @
NS        @ =>  ns1.gamuru.com
NS        @ =>  ns65.domaincontrol.com
```

([more info here about gamuru.com here](http://jelisavacwlan.hr/img/gd.png) )

DNS record on gamuru:

```
type name               Data    Prio    TTL 
A   centartepiha.hr.    144.76.173.238  0   3600    
A   mail            144.76.173.238  0   3600    
A   www         144.76.173.238  0   3600    
MX  centartepiha.hr.    mail.centartepiha.hr.   10  3600    
NS  centartepiha.hr.    ns1.gamuru.com. 0   3600    
NS  centartepiha.hr.    ns1.xname.org.  0   86400   
NS  centartepiha.hr.    ns0.xname.org.  0   3600
```

DNS record on xname:

```
centartepiha.hr.        IN  SOA ns0.xname.org.  9a3bsp.gmail.com. (
                2013101001  ; serial
                10800   ; Refresh period
                3600    ; Retry interval
                604800  ; Expire time
                10800   ; Negative caching TTL
            )

$ORIGIN centartepiha.hr.
            IN      NS      ns1.gamuru.com.
            IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
            IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
            IN      NS      ns2.xname.org.
centartepiha.hr.            IN      A       144.76.173.238
```

What am I doing wrong? Or whole setup is just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you query TLD servers for .hr name servers, 4 answers are returned:

> ```
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION (4  records)
> hr.   172800  IN  NS  sns-pb.isc.org.
> hr.   172800  IN  NS  ns5.univie.ac.at.
> hr.   172800  IN  NS  n3ns.nic.es.
> hr.   172800  IN  NS  hr-ns-1.carnet.hr.
> ```

That is fine, so let's check the first one (all 4 will respond with the same answer):

hr-ns-1.carnet.hr returns two name servers for doman centartepiha.hr

> ```
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION (2  records)
> centartepiha.hr.  14440   IN  NS  ns1.gamuru.com.
> centartepiha.hr.  14440   IN  NS  ns1.xname.org.
> ```

Let's check ns1.gamuru.com for www.centartepiha.hr first:

> ```
> ;; ANSWER SECTION (1  record)
> www.centartepiha.hr.  3600    IN  A   144.76.173.238
> ```

That is OK, and that is why centartepiha.hr sometimes works

Let's check ns1.xname.org for www.centartepiha.hr:

> ```
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;www.centartepiha.hr.           IN      A
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: centartepiha.hr.        86400   IN      SOA    
> ns0.xname.org. 9a3bsp.gmail.com. 2013100401 10800 3600 604800 10800
> ```

No answer here. You should add A record for www.centartepiha.hr on ns1.xname.org.

Other than that, ns1.gamuru.com is configured as NS for gamuru.com domain, but the query for gamuru.com @144.76.173.238 is refused (luckily ns66.domaincontrol.com responds fine), you should fix this also.

[www.dnsstuff.com](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport%7Ctype=domain&&value=centartepiha.hr) and [dns.squish.net](http://dns.squish.net/) will give you a lot of valuable info.

EDIT: If you are only looking to resolve centartepiha.hr (without www), you just have to fix ns1.gamuru.com

Answer (score 1):

The following name servers do not return A record

```
dig A centartepiha.hr @ns65.domaincontrol.com +short

Returns no record
```

The following ones are OK:

```
dig A centartepiha.hr @ns0.xname.org +short
dig A centartepiha.hr @ns1.gamuru.com +short
dig A centartepiha.hr @ns1.xname.org +short
```

All above return:
    144.76.173.238

Add a record for domain in the name server domaincontrol.com